# How to retrieve the type of CRS (geographic or projected)?

Tags: coordinate-system, java, geotools

Is there a way with [GeoTools](https://geotools.org/) to know whether a CRS is geographic (in degrees) or projected (in meter) ?

I have tried empirically with the following code (based on a check of the CRS unit) but I am not sure at all if it is going to work for all CRSs... Is there a better and more correct way ?

```
public enum CRSType { GEOG, CARTO, UNKNOWN }

private static CRSType getCRSType(Unit<?> unit) {
    if(unit == null) return CRSType.UNKNOWN;
    switch (unit.toString()) {
    case "": return CRSType.UNKNOWN;
    case "°": return CRSType.GEOG;
    case "deg": return CRSType.GEOG;
    case "dms": return CRSType.GEOG;
    case "degree": return CRSType.GEOG;
    case "m": return CRSType.CARTO;
    default:
        LOGGER.warn("Unexpected unit of measure for projection: "+unit);
        return CRSType.UNKNOWN;
    }
}

public static CRSType getCRSType(CoordinateReferenceSystem crs) {
    return getCRSType(CRSUtilities.getUnit(crs.getCoordinateSystem()));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a more reliable method (since you've overlooked feet and chains to name but two) is to check if your projection is an instance of `DefaultGeographicCRS` or `DefaultProjectedCRS`. Theoretically, it could also be a `DefaultEngineeringCRS` (which I think is neither), a `DefaultGeocentricCRS`, a `DefaultImageCRS` (that I've never seen in the wild) or a temporal or vertical CRS (again probably not what you want anyway).

So I came up with the following test code which seems to give the expected answers:

```
ArrayList<CoordinateReferenceSystem> crsList = new ArrayList<>();
CoordinateReferenceSystem wgs84 = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
crsList.add(wgs84);
String[] codes = { "4326", "27700", "5243", "5673", "4087", "42309", "26956", "8857" };
for (String code : codes) {
  CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:" + code);
  crsList.add(crs);
}
for (CoordinateReferenceSystem crs : crsList) {
  System.out.println(crs);
  if ((crs instanceof DefaultGeographicCRS))
    System.out.println(crs.getName().getCode() + " is geographic");
  if ((crs instanceof DefaultProjectedCRS))
    System.out.println(crs.getName().getCode() + " is projected");
}
```

### Update

A slightly cleaner method would be to look for `org.opengis.referencing.crs.ProjectedCRS` and `org.opengis.referencing.crs.GeographicCRS`

Comment: It might be worth proposing this as an enhancement to the CRS class if you get it to work.

Comment: Thanks a lo Ian. It tested it on few other known CRSs and it worked as well. It is more reliable than what I was doing so far.